# What could be adding "Pragma:no-cache" to my response Headers? (Apache, PHP)

Tags: php, apache, caching, http-headers, pragma

I have a website which maintenance I've inherited, which is a big hairy mess.
One of the things I'm doing is improving performance. Among other things, I'm adding `Expires` headers to images.

Now, there are some images that are served through a PHP file, and I notice that they do have the `Expires` header, but they also get loaded every time.

Looking at Response Headers, I see this:

```
Expires Wed, 15 Jun 2011 18:11:55 GMT
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma  no-cache
```

Which obviously explains the problem.

Now, I've looked all over the code base, and it doesn't say "pragma" anywhere. .htaccess doesn't seem to have anything related either.

Any ideas what could be setting those "pragma" (and "cache-control") headers, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Run `grep -R pragma .` to look through the files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a simple file that includes none of your PHP libraries but lives in the same folder as the file that serves up your images through a PHP file.

```
file: test.php
```

Request this file through a browser and check the headers.  If you see the Response headers that you don't want, you know that they're configured via apache and not generated via a PHP file and you can concentrate your searches on .htaccess file in the directory tree, and on the http.confg and other included apache config files.  You'll want to search for

```
<Directory....
```

and

```
<VirtualHost
```

sections that may apply to your site.

If you don't see the headers in a request for that simple PHP file, you know that PHP is setting the headers somewhere.  At the end of your image serving file (or right after it echos the image and exits), but the following PHP snippet)

```
var_dump(get_included_files());
```

Request an image through the image serving URL.  That above snippet will print out all the PHP files used in the request. (you'll probably need to view source or use curl to see the raw output, as the browser will report an invalid image)

Having a subset of your files to work file, search through them for calls to the

```
header();
```

function.  The `header` function is the only way (I think) that raw PHP code can set Response headers.  You'll also want to search for

```
call_user_func
eval
$$
```

in case there's any dynamic code on the page that's using PHP's meta-programming capabilities to call the `header` function.

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed answer. It's definitely Apache's configuration, but I don't have access to it. I only have FTP access to my website's directory. Any idea how I can override/remove these headers using only my .htaccess files?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's too general to quickly come up with an answer.  You'd need to know which Apache directives were causing the caching in over to override the effects AND need to know if they were overridable in .htacess AND know the syntax to do so.  Rather than waste too much time I'd raise this up the chain to the server admins and see if they can't help you, as "caching by default" isn't the default configuration of Apache and/or the PHP module.  #nothelpfulsorry

Comment: In regard to Apache2 settings, you should search ALL the files. It could be hidden in a file down under in a sub-directory *who knows where*... Also, search all your data directories since you may have a .htaccess at any level there. In my case it was in the `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/server-cgi-bin.conf`.

Answer (score 31):

The culprit may be php.ini, where session.cache_limiter=nocache.  Change the value to blank or public to avoid the anti-cacheing headers.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the default value of session.cache_limiter ('nocache') to '' and it solved the problem.

Comment: To "public", wouldn't that be dangerous for a website that has some private pages?

Comment: Presumably that's limiting caching to public documents only.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem with `Pragma: nocache`

`session_cache_limiter(false);` prior to `session_start();` seemed to suppress it.

Answer (score 10):

Try unsetting the headers in `.htaccess`. The below example will unset them for all files matching the extensions `ico`, `jpeg`, `png`, `gif`, `js`, `css`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Pragma
</FilesMatch>
```

You can find some hints in [this article](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/#Implementing_Caching_Scheme_htaccess).

Answer (score 4):

I did this at runtime with this:

```
header("Pragma:");
```

which forced the script to unset the Pragma header.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in .htaccess it may be in the main Apache config file - or one of its includes, depending on the setup.

Comment: Any ideas how to override it from my .htaccess? (I don't have SSH access to this server, or access to httpd.conf)

Comment: Not sure how to *remove* a header actually - try asking on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting for people with similar problems that many frameworks will auto-add headers especially caching ones. It's fairly easy to overload them either in the framework library or within your app.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I know that Zend auto-adds headers. The headers can be overloaded via php's header tag as shown by Michael or the framework will have their particular function to do it. For Zend you have to use setHeader()